# HttpResponse get access to original URL

Tags: spring, apache, httpclient, httpresponse

I'm working on a system I didn't write.  I need to add a ResponseInterceptor but in order for it to correctly handle the response it needs access to the original URL.  This is not part of what is in the Response Interceptor, or HttpContext API.  Is there an attribute that is set by default inside of the apache HTTPClient that allows me to get this information?